# Soap Parsing issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, soap

I need to parse a Soap Request ,but i am having the following problem , can someone help me solving this ,as i am new to soap .let me know if you need any other information about the code

Here is the Soap Request

```
POST /LocatorAPI/LocatorService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: staging2.abc.spatialpoint.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://spatialpoint.com/abc/locator/FindNearby"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<FindNearby xmlns="http://spatialpoint.com/abc/locator/">
  <request>         <Token>string</Token>
  </request>
</FindNearby>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

here is my objective c Code .

```
NSString* soapMessage = 
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
 @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>",
 @"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">",
 @"<soap:Body>",
 @"<FindByProperty xmlns=\"http://spatialpoint.com/abc/locator/ \">",
 @"<request>",
 @"<Token>",
 theRadius,
 @"</Token>",
 @"</request>",
 @"</FindByProperty>",
 @"</soap:Body>",
 @"</soap:Envelope>"];




NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://staging2.abc.spatialpoint.com/LocatorAPI/LocatorService.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// HTTP headers
NSString *messageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
[req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[req addValue:messageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
// method = POST
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// BODY
[req setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// send request
self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self]; 
if (self.connection != nil)
{ 
    self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]      
     setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```

and i am getting this Error .

```
2013-06-19 02:22:49.942 SoapClient[42229:c07] Response:
2013-06-19 02:22:49.943 SoapClient[42229:c07] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault>

<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP

Header SOAPAction: .</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the HTTP field SOAPAction to the request:

```
[req setValue:@"http://spatialpoint.com/abc/locator/FindNearby" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
```

Also consider to check [this project](http://sudzc.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to put this in a comment, but it's too large.  Here is my soap request code:

```
    soapMsg =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
     "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">"
     "<soap12:Body>"
     "<WebServiceMethod xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
     "<MessageToServer><![CDATA[%@]]></MessageToServer>"
     "</WebServiceMethod>"
     "</soap12:Body>"
     "</soap12:Envelope>"
     ,encryptedString];
```

Where encryptedString is the message my server receives and decrypts.  WebServiceMethod is the method name in my webservices and MessageToServer is the name of the object that the webservice asks for.

I am also using `ASIFormDataRequest` instead of `NSMutableURLRequest`.  That may make a difference.  ASIHTTP library has been very good to me.

Another bit.  My Content-Type is `@"application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"`  Honestly I don't know what it should be, you may know more than me in that regard.  Just thought I might mention it since it appears to be your header that the server is not understanding.

Comment: i cannot use the ASIHTTP is not Supported anymore .

Comment: Why are you setting the message length twice?  And check out my edit for another bit that may help you, may not.